# Pass from table to longtable

Tags: longtable

i saw other posts to try to solve my problem... but I'm still quite troubled. I need to pass a table to longtable, i used a table generator online and got this code:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular} {|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\#                      & Actividades                                                                                                                                                                                                   & Objetivos                                                 & Duracion Estimada \\     \hline
1                       & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Redaccion del documento de \\     Trabajo de Grado\end{tabular}                                                                                                                        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                     & 12 semanas        \\     \hline
2                       & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Redacci\'on\\ del documento     de\\  Trabajo Especial de Grado\end{tabular}                                                                                                             & Todos                                                     & 23 semanas        \\     \hline
3                       & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Realizar un estudio de los     requisitos \\ existentes en los horarios del\\          Departamento de     computaci\'on\end{tabular}                                                          &     1.1                                                       & 2 semanas         \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{4} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Construir\\ la representaci\'on     \\ adecuada de un horario de clases \\ del departamento\\ de computaci\'on\end{tabular}                                                                & 1.1                                                       & 2 semanas         \\         \hline
5                       & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Definir\\ las estructuras     necesarias \\ para guardar la informaci\'on de \\ todos los\\ elementos involucrados\\      en la asignaci\'on de horarios\end{tabular}                      & 1.1 y 1.2                                                     & 2 semanas         \\ \hline
6                       & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Codificar\\ ambas     metaheur\'isticas \\ usando un lenguaje de \\ programaci\'on de alto\\ nivel     adecuado\end{tabular}                                                               &     \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}1.2, 1.3 y\\ 1.4\end{tabular}  & 5 semanas         \\ \hline
7                       & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Determinar la matriz de     feromonas\\  y n\'umero de hormigas ideal\end{tabular}                                                                                                       & 1.2 y 1.4                                                 & 2 semanas         \\     \hline
8                       & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Definir los movimientos, \\     condiciones tab\'u, \\ criterios de aspiraci\'on mediante\\ la aplicaci\'on de pruebas     para \\ optimizar el c\'alculo de la \\ soluci\'on final\end{tabular} & 1.3 y 1.4                                                     & 2 semanas         \\ \hline
9                       & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Establecer el nivel de     hibridizaci\'on \\ entre ambas metaheur\'isticas\end{tabular}                                                                                                   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}1.2, 1.3 \\ y 1.4\end{tabular} & 2 semanas         \\     \hline
10                      & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Crear\\ distintos casos de     prueba\\ basados en modelos de entradas de datos\\  sintetizadospara la asignaci\'on de     horarios\end{tabular}                                         & 2.1                                                           & 2 semanas         \\ \hline
11                      & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Realizar pruebas finales\\  que     permitan precisar \\ el comportamiento y eficiencia\\ del programa frente a los \\     distintos casos de prueba establecidos\end{tabular}         & 2.1                                                           & 2 semanas         \\ \hline
12                      & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Realizar el an\'alisis\\  de     los resultados usando\\  las m\'etricas definidas\end{tabular}                                                                                            & 2.2                                                       & 2 semanas         \\     \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I erased the \begin and \end table and replaced tabular by longtable
It throws me this error:
! Argument of \LT@nofcols has an extra }
& \begin{longtable}[c]{@{}c@{}}
    Redaccion del documento de...

Comment: only the outer tabular should be changed, not all of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not nest `longtable`: just use `longtable` for the outer table, and `tabular` for the inner ones.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable} {|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\#                      & Actividades                                                                                                                                                                                                   & Objetivos                                                 &
 \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Duracion\\ Estimada\end{tabular} \\     \hline
1                       & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Redaccion del documento de \\     Trabajo de Grado\end{tabular}                                                                                                                        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                     & 12 semanas        \\     \hline
2                       & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Redacci\'on\\ del documento     de\\  Trabajo Especial de Grado\end{tabular}                                                                                                             & Todos                                                     & 23 semanas        \\     \hline
3                       & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Realizar un estudio de los     requisitos \\ existentes en los horarios del\\          Departamento de     computaci\'on\end{tabular}                                                          &     1.1                                                       & 2 semanas         \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{4} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Construir\\ la representaci\'on     \\ adecuada de un horario de clases \\ del departamento\\ de computaci\'on\end{tabular}                                                                & 1.1                                                       & 2 semanas         \\         \hline
5                       & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Definir\\ las estructuras     necesarias \\ para guardar la informaci\'on de \\ todos los\\ elementos involucrados\\      en la asignaci\'on de horarios\end{tabular}                      & 1.1 y 1.2                                                     & 2 semanas         \\ \hline
6                       & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Codificar\\ ambas     metaheur\'isticas \\ usando un lenguaje de \\ programaci\'on de alto\\ nivel     adecuado\end{tabular}                                                               &     \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}1.2, 1.3 y\\ 1.4\end{tabular}  & 5 semanas         \\ \hline
7                       & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Determinar la matriz de     feromonas\\  y n\'umero de hormigas ideal\end{tabular}                                                                                                       & 1.2 y 1.4                                                 & 2 semanas         \\     \hline
8                       & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Definir los movimientos, \\     condiciones tab\'u, \\ criterios de aspiraci\'on mediante\\ la aplicaci\'on de pruebas     para \\ optimizar el c\'alculo de la \\ soluci\'on final\end{tabular} & 1.3 y 1.4                                                     & 2 semanas         \\ \hline
9                       & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Establecer el nivel de     hibridizaci\'on \\ entre ambas metaheur\'isticas\end{tabular}                                                                                                   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}1.2, 1.3 \\ y 1.4\end{tabular} & 2 semanas         \\     \hline
10                      & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Crear\\ distintos casos de     prueba\\ basados en modelos de entradas de datos\\  sintetizadospara la asignaci\'on de     horarios\end{tabular}                                         & 2.1                                                           & 2 semanas         \\ \hline
11                      & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Realizar pruebas finales\\  que     permitan precisar \\ el comportamiento y eficiencia\\ del programa frente a los \\     distintos casos de prueba establecidos\end{tabular}         & 2.1                                                           & 2 semanas         \\ \hline
12                      & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Realizar el an\'alisis\\  de     los resultados usando\\  las m\'etricas definidas\end{tabular}                                                                                            & 2.2                                                       & 2 semanas         \\     \hline

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```